# How to use var javascript in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

How to use a javascript variable when setting the `innerHTML` of an element? To see my problem first click `CLICK 1`. This will show `delete` and then click `delete`. Why does the alert not show `111-aaaa,1`? How can I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/brf75wvp/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test_id" value="1"/>
<div onclick="test_fn1()">CLICK 1</div>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
    function test_fn1() {
        var test_id_val = document.getElementById("test_id").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick= delete_fn('111-aaaa, test_id_val')>delete</span>";
    };
</script>

<script>
    function delete_fn(no_delete) {
        alert(no_delete);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean **Why not alert 111-aaaa,1**

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately. This had nothing to do with jquery, css, html nor ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the variable with string like following.

```
function test_fn1() {
    var test_id_val = document.getElementById("test_id").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick=delete_fn('111-aaaa,"+test_id_val+"')>delete</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variable to string:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick=delete_fn('111-aaaa," + test_id_val + "')>delete</span>";
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/brf75wvp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error. Correct one is:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick=delete_fn('111-aaaa," + test_id_val + "')>delete</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code having some error try using bellow this will work

```
<script>
function test_fn1() {
var test_id_val = document.getElementById("test_id").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<span onclick=delete_fn("111-aaaa,'+test_id_val+'")>delete</span>';
};
</script>
```